# Laws of large numbers for sample covariances when each random sample are just known to be integrable random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, independence

Crossposted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432957/laws-of-large-numbers-for-sample-covariances-when-each-random-sample-are-just-kn

Let $X_1,...X_n$ be $p$-dimensional random sample, i.e. they're iid random vactors, each with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$. Let $\bar{X_n}:= \frac{1}{n}(X_1+...+X_n)$ be their sample mean. Denote by $C_n$ the sample covariance matrix 
$C_n:= \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X_n}) (X_i - \bar{X_n})'$, where ' denotes the transpose of a matrix.

Let's not assume anything for the moment, on the distribution of each $X_i$.

(1) Then, does $C_n \to \Sigma$ almost surely when $n \to \infty$? (General SLLN for sample covariance for any random samples).

(2) If we assume each $X_i$ to be normal, then is (1) true? (SLLN for covariance of normal random samples).

(3) If we assume each $X_i$ to be normal as well as $\mu = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^p, \Sigma= I_p$, then is (1) true? (SLLN for covariance of standard normal random samples )

Comment: (1) Yes, assuming $\Sigma$ exists. Write $C_n = \overline{X_n X_n'} - \bar{X}_n \bar{X}_n'$ and use the continuous mapping theorem. (2) Yes, by (1). (3) Yes, by (1).

Comment: @Galton thank you for byour comment, and I do see the motivation behind using the continuing mapping theorem (more in 2) )). But I'd like to ask you two follow up questions:



1) What's your $X_n$, when you wrote the notation $\bar{X_n X_n'}$? In my notation, $X_n$ is just the $n$-th random sample. I understand that the symbol $\bar{X_n}$ you wrote is the sample mean, same symbol as mine.

Comment: Sample mean of the outer products, $n^{-1}\sum_{i =1}^nX_i X_i’$

Comment: @Galton Thanks, but still have a question! [contd] 2) The population covariance $\Sigma = E(X_1X_1') - \mu\mu'$. And I see that by SLLN, the right part in sample cov. goes to $\mu.\mu'$. No problem there. For the left part, how do show that $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i}X_iX_i' \to E(X_1X_1')$? I guess we need to apply cont mapping thm, but on which function? For example, how do you prove e.g. that $1/n \Sigma_{i} X_{i1}X_{i2} \to E(X_1X_1')(1,2)$ a.s.? To prove it, don't we need to furst prive that $X_{i1}X_{i2}, 1 \leq i \leq n$ are iid? How can we just use the cont mapping theorem to prove it?

Comment: View the outer product $X_iX_i'$ as vector in $\mathbb{R}^{p^2}$. The elements of that vector may be dependent but $X_iX_i'$ and $X_jX_j'$ for $i\neq j$ are independent and identically distributed. More generally, the $X_iX_i'$ are a sequence of iid matrices to which the SLLN can be applied directly. The dependence within the vector/matrix is irrelevant. The SLLN would only fail if  dependence spilled from $X_iX_i'$ to  $X_jX_j'$. SLLN implies that $\overline{X_nX_n'}$ and $\bar{X}_n$ converge. $C_n$ is continuous in $\overline{X_nX_n'}$ and $\bar{X}_n$. Now use continuous mapping theorem.